# Adding custom uiView to UITableViewCell imageView property

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a custom uiview to asynchronously download and change its image property upon success.

I'm able to add a static image to a UITableViewCell with style UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle with the following code:

```
        CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(-20, -20, 40, 40);
        cell.imageView.frame = viewRect;

        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"example"]];
        [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor];
        [cell.imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imageView.frame.size.width/1.25];
```

but when I try to add my custom UIView via :

```
        PAAImageView *avatarView = [[PAAImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.imageView.frame backgroundProgressColor:[UIColor whiteColor] progressColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [cell.imageView addSubview:avatarView];
        [cell.imageView bringSubviewToFront:avatarView];
        [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor];
        [cell.imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imageView.frame.size.width/1.25];
```

The custom UIView never shows up. Is there a separate way to do this ?

**EDIT**

I'm assigning a placeholder image and then putting PAAImageview on top of it. Same as before to set the static image, the below adds the view but it is still sized at frame (-20, -20, 40, 40) while cell.imageView is being blown up (I think because of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill). How can I get this PAAImageView on TOP of the placeholder image ?

```
        PAAImageView *avatarView = [[PAAImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.imageView.bounds backgroundProgressColor:[UIColor whiteColor] progressColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [avatarView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        avatarView.progressColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [cell addSubview:avatarView];
```

Comment: You are adding the custom UIView to the imageView, is that what you want? maybe you need to addSubview to cell, not to the imageView.

Comment: @FabioCardoso But then doesn't the text not resize, one of the benefits of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle ?

Comment: The cell's imageView only appears and is sized when you assign an image to it. You never assign an image to `cell.imageView` so it's frame will never be set. This means the view you add to the image view won't be seen. You create create your own custom cell class with your `PAAImageView` and two labels as needed. Then you can layout the three views as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy that makes sense. I'd prefer to add a placeholder image and then return the `cell.imageView.frame`, and set `PAAImageView` on top of that. But when I try the above, it doesn't return the correct frame. Why is that ? I'll edit which shows my new code

Comment: The cell isn't laid out in `cellForRow...`. You can adjust the frame in the `willDisplayCell...` method.

Comment: @rmaddy moving into willDisplaycell returns the same frame, the one I initialized (-20, -20, 40, 40). But the actual image is large. Is this because of  the line that calls `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this and posting a solution for those interested. The below works but can clearly be refactored to a general case.

The key was to NOT set my custom view `avatarView.frame = cell.imageView` because the frame size and width were being adjusted when the `cell.imageView` was drawn. I'm not really sure WHY, but setting the `avatarView.frame.size.width or height = 1.5 * cell.imageView.frame.size.width or height` worked.

It may be because setting the `[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill]` resizes the frame at the time they are drawn, or `cell.imageView` ignores its frame property when drawn. OR `[cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imageView.frame.size.width/1.25];` threw something off.

Even setting `avatarView.frame = cell.imageView` in `willDisplayCell`did not work.

I tested this on a bunch of different screens and it worked. Also manually changing the first line to `CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(-20, -20, 60, 60);` &  `CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(-40, -40, 60, 60);` & `CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(-40, -40, 80, 80);` did not work as the image no longer comes out round.

**actual code**

```
//manually assigning frame to imageView and image
 CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(-20, -20, 40, 40);
 cell.imageView.frame = viewRect;
 [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"example"]];

//adding actual image. 
  PAAImageView *avatarView = [[PAAImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.imageView.bounds.origin.x, cell.imageView.bounds.origin.y, cell.imageView.frame.size.width*1.5, cell.imageView.frame.size.height*1.5) backgroundProgressColor:[UIColor whiteColor] progressColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
  [cell.imageView addSubview:avatarView];
  [cell.imageView bringSubviewToFront:avatarView];

  //adjusting image view to cirle
  [cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor];
  [cell.imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
  [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
  [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
  [cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imageView.frame.size.width/1.25];
```